# How du calculate the volume of sand filled in a box with a camera

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, point-clouds, stereo-3d

I have a box with a known volume. This box is filled with sand. Is it possible to calculate the volume of the sand?

I'm thinking about cameras around this box making a picture and generating a point cloud to calculate the content.

Has anyone done something like that before or has anyone an idea how I can do that?

[image]

Comment: please review [ask]. where is your research, where is your attempt to solve the problem? having an idea is not enough to post a question.

Comment: You need to improve your question, what is the specific problem? I guess LiDAR would be better for your application, though.